# Issue with Autocomplete after Upgrading from Gatsby 2 to Gatsby 5: 'autocompleteService.current' Null Reference

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gatsby

I recently upgraded from Gatsby 2 to Gatsby 5, and I've encountered an issue with my Autocomplete functionality. After the update, the Autocomplete no longer behaves as expected.

Upon investigation, I found that when attempting to search for a specific city, the AutocompleteService's current property is null. This seems to be caused by the 'places' object being undefined.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    if (!autocompleteService.current && get(window, 'google.maps.places.AutocompleteService')) {
        autocompleteService.current = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    }
    if (!autocompleteService.current) {
        return undefined;
    }

    if (inputValue !== '') {
        getPlacePredictionsMemo(
            {
                input: inputValue,
                componentRestrictions: { country: getCurrentCountryCodeForMarket() },
            },
            results => {
                if (active) {
                    setOptions([].concat(stations, results));
                }
            }
        );
    }

    return () => {
        active = false;
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [inputValue, getPlacePredictionsMemo, setOptions]);
```

I've noticed that the autocompleteService.current is not being initialized properly due to the 'places' object being undefined. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Hello! You might want to file an issue in the github repo itself, have you already tried it?